# Vim creates strange output when navigating up or down in Amazon EC2 Ubuntu

Tags: vim, ubuntu-11.04, amazon-ec2

When navigating up or down in Vim whilst  ssh-ed into an Amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance, strange output appears at the bottom of the screen.

-I think the right-most info (e.g. 2,0-) is indicating cursor location.

This doesn't happen when using Vim locally. I'm new to Vim. Any ideas? I don't have a ~/.vimrc file...

Check out this screenshot:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8948326/Screen%20Shot%202012-08-10%20at%201.36.46%20PM.png

Comment: What AMI id are you running and in what region?

Comment: Logging out and logging back in fixed it. 

...And...I'm officially the jerk who didn't try restarting...

Comment: Someone suggest logging in and out and I'll mark theirs as the correct answer (I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question yet). Yay for points!